# Not all columns show up on select * on DB2 for IBM i

Tags: db2, iseries

My client has a table on their IBMi with a foreign key to another table. It's not showing up with a `SELECT * FROM lib.table`. However, if I specifically mention it in the column list. It does show up.

```
SELECT
        col1, col2.col3, fxcolid
    FROM  lib.table
```

I'm using the jt400 driver to query from [SQLWorkbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be long column name versus short column name. Upon closer inspection the **hidden** column always had the same value as an unhidden one. Since the long name in this case was abbreviated and cryptic, I didn't make that connection right away.

Answer (score 5):

There is an `IMPLICITLY HIDDEN` column attribute that can be applied. Please check for this...

This means the column will only appear when it is explicitly specified on the `SELECT` statement.

Check the `CREATE TABLE` statement for this property, or materialize the TABLE's DDL using some API or tool, such as RTVSQLSRC.

Comment: I was stupid. It was actually long (what shows up in STRSQL results on the green screen) versus short table names. See my self answer.